# Creating an export file for model in blender

Tags: python, export

I am totally a newbie to Blender and python scripting in Blender.

What I am trying to do is write a script for one of my models in the Crate.blend file in the scene to extract its vertices and face information and printing it to the console

I use the Blender text editor to write a simple script like below and run the script. This runs fine on the console

```
import bpy
for item in bpy.data.objects:  

    if item.name == 'Crate':
        if item.type == 'MESH':
            for face in item.data.polygons:
                verts_in_face = face.vertices[:]
                print("face index ", face.index)
                print("normal ", face.normal)
                for vert in verts_in_face:
                    print("vertex coords ", item.data.vertices[vert].co)
```

What I want is to execute this script when I type the following line in the console

```
blender --background crate.blend --python export-model.py -- Crate
```

How do I go about achieving this? I think I might need to create an exporter script for the same? I found a promising post for creating an exporter script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079106/how-do-i-get-a-blender-exporter-script-to-run-from-the-command-line)

I will paste the script just in case

```
# Required Blender information.
bl_info = {
           "name": "My Exporter",
           "author": "",
           "version": (1, 0),
           "blender": (2, 65, 0),
           "location": "File > Export > Test (.tst)",
           "description": "",
           "warning": "",
           "wiki_url": "",
           "tracker_url": "",
           "category": "Import-Export"
          }

# Import the Blender required namespaces.
import sys, getopt

import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper



# The main exporter class.
class MyExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
   bl_idname       = "export_scene.my_exporter";
   bl_label        = "My Exporter";
   bl_options      = {'PRESET'};

   filename_ext    = ".tst";

   object_count    = 0;

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def execute(self, context):
      print("Execute was called.");

      self.parse_command_line_options();

      if (self.filepath == ""):
         print("No sutable filename was provided to save to.");
         return {'FINISHED'};

      # Get all the mesh objects in the scene.
      objList = [object for object in bpy.context.scene.objects if object.type == 'MESH'];

      # Now process all the objects that we found.
      for gameObject in objList:
         self.export_object(gameObject);

      # Parse all the objects in the scene.
      return {'FINISHED'};


   def export_object(self, gameObject):
      if (gameObject.type != "MESH"):
         print("Object was not of type mesh.");
      else:
         self.object_count += 1;

      return;


   def parse_command_line_options(self):
      modelFile = "";
      myArgs = [];
      argsStartPos = 0;

      if (("--" in sys.argv) == False):
         return;

      argsStartPos = sys.argv.index("--");
      argsStartPos += 1;
      myArgs = sys.argv[argsStartPos:];

      try:
         opts, args = getopt.getopt(myArgs, 'hm:', ["help", "model-file="]);
      except getOpt.GetoptError:
         print("Opt Error.");
         return;

      for opt, arg in opts:
         if (opt in ("-h", "--help")):
            print("Run this as the following blender command.");
            print("\tblender <blend file> --background --python <script file> -- -m <output file>");
         elif (opt in ("-m", "--model-file")):
            modelFile = arg;

      if (modelFile != ""):
         self.filepath = modelFile;



# Define a function to create the menu option for exporting.
def create_menu(self, context):
   self.layout.operator(MyExporter.bl_idname,text="test (.tst)");

# Define the Blender required registration functions.
def register():
   """
   Handles the registration of the Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.register_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(create_menu);

def unregister():
   """
   Handles the unregistering of this Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(create_menu);


# Handle running the script from Blender's text editor.
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
   print("Registering.");
   register();

   print("Executing.");
   bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter();
```

I run this script inside Blender text editor and it compiles

Now when I try to run it on the command line with the below command

```
blender model.blend --background --python myexporter.py
```

it thrown exception on model.blend as "invalid syntax"

I am completely new to Blender and scripting with python so spare me if I am missing something here.

Thanks

---

After changing my script as suggested in the second post, I get the following error

[image]

My blender file name is "model.blend" and it throws the error as invalid syntax. What am I missing?

Comment: both scripts run fine, how are executing the command line ? do you have the script file with the blend file in the same directory ?  and for how you implement your exporter change the exporter function body with your code and modify parse func

Comment: Yes I have them in the same directory. Does it have to be a specific directory or any directory is fine? I just created a directory under my documents and pasted all the files in there

Comment: Does it have to do something with running the right version of Blender and python? I am using Blender v2.72

Comment: The console inside blender is a Python console - instead run `blender model.blend --back...` from your system console/terminal.

Comment: @Htlcs you have to add blender path to the 'PATH' system variable to be able to execute the command in any folder or use the method in the answer

Comment: lose the semicolons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work for  a command line :

```
blender myfile.blend --background --python myexporter.py -- -m myobject
```

where :

```
blender <blender file>  --background  --python <script file> -- -m <object name>
```

i have removed 'Crate' you can set the name of the object in the command line ^ ,and removed the the file output since you are only printing to the console .

**UPDATE:**

as sambler noted you should be running this in a terminal, here is the steps "for windows":

- copy the script in a new text file then rename it to exporter.py   "be sure to change the extension from .txt to .py"
- go to your blender installation folder  "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender"
- put your .blend file and exporter.py in this folder
- hit <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>right click</kbd> to open a CMD in this folder
- type the command  as follows :

  blender model.blend --background --python exporter.py -- -m Crate

***Note :*** *you don't need to open blender for any of these steps 'nothing is done inside blender'*

This is the script :

```
# Required Blender information.
bl_info = {
           "name": "My Exporter",
           "author": "",
           "version": (1, 0),
           "blender": (2, 65, 0),
           "location": "File > Export > Test (.tst)",
           "description": "",
           "warning": "",
           "wiki_url": "",
           "tracker_url": "",
           "category": "Import-Export"
          }

# Import the Blender required namespaces.
import sys, getopt

import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ExportHelper

# The main exporter class.
class MyExporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
   bl_idname       = "export_scene.my_exporter";
   bl_label        = "My Exporter";
   bl_options      = {'PRESET'};

   obj_name        = "";

   def __init__(self):
      pass

   def execute(self, context):
      print("Execute was called.");

      self.parse_command_line_options();

      if (self.obj_name == ""):
         print("No suitable object name was provided .");
         return {'FINISHED'};
      print("Executing......");
      # Now start exporting the target object.
      self.export_object(self.obj_name);
      # Parse all the objects in the scene.
      print("Finished");
      return {'FINISHED'};


   def export_object(self, obj_name):
       for item in bpy.data.objects:
           if item.name == obj_name and item.type == 'MESH' :
              for face in item.data.polygons:
                  verts_in_face = face.vertices[:]
                  print("face index ", face.index)
                  print("normal ", face.normal)
                  for vert in verts_in_face:
                  print("vertex coords ", item.data.vertices[vert].co)


   def parse_command_line_options(self):
      obj_name = "";
      myArgs = [];
      argsStartPos = 0;

      if (("--" in sys.argv) == False):
         return;

      argsStartPos = sys.argv.index("--");
      argsStartPos += 1;
      myArgs = sys.argv[argsStartPos:];

      try:
         opts, args = getopt.getopt(myArgs, 'hm:', ["help", "model-file="]);
      except getOpt.GetoptError:
         print("Opt Error.");
         return;

      for opt, arg in opts:
         if (opt in ("-h", "--help")):
            print("Run this as the following blender command.");
            print("\tblender <blend file> --background --python <script file> -- -m <Object name>");
         elif (opt == "-m"):
            obj_name = arg;

      if (obj_name != ""):
         self.obj_name = obj_name;
         print(obj_name);

# Define a function to create the menu option for exporting.
def create_menu(self, context):
   self.layout.operator(MyExporter.bl_idname,text="test (.tst)");

# Define the Blender required registration functions.
def register():
   """
   Handles the registration of the Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.register_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.append(create_menu);

def unregister():
   """
   Handles the unregistering of this Blender Addon.
   """
   bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__);
   bpy.types.INFO_MT_file_export.remove(create_menu);


# Handle running the script from Blender's text editor.
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
   print("Registering.");
   register();

   print("Executing.");
   bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter();
```

Comment: thanks a lot.

I tried what you said. Pasted your script as it is, but I get the error in the image that I have attached in my first post. My blender file name is model.blend so I don't understand what the error means :(

Comment: @Htlcs you're welcome, are you using windows ? if so you should add the blender path to system variables so you can work on any folder

Comment: Yes I am running it on Windows 8. I would definitely do what you suggested. Thanks a lot mate!

Comment: I had a question. What do the register() modules do? Do I write it because I do not have blender path to system variables defined? I understand how the rest of the code works except  the registration part.

Comment: @Htlcs the register adds the exporter to blender UI "File->Export->myExporter" and add it to the operators "bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter"  so you don't need to run the script each time to use it you either use the menu or from python console type "bpy.ops.export_scene.my_exporter"

Answer (score 0):

The final image shows you entering the command in blender's python console, which only understands python. The command you are typing is a shell command and it needs to be typed into a terminal emulator, sometimes called the CLI or Command Line Interface.

How to start the terminal emulator will depend on what OS you are using, [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terminal_emulators) lists some terminal emulators for different platforms. Most systems will have one of them installed by default.